# Symfony 2.8 | Twig | app.user and app.session null in stage env, ok in local and prod

Tags: php, symfony, twig, session-variables, symfony-2.8

I am developing on an old project that uses Symfony 2.8.

I develop *locally* and in the Twig I can correctly use `{{app.user.username}}` or other like `{{app.session...}}`.
When I deploy it in a *staging environment* those values are always blank.
Then if I deploy it in *production*, the global `app` variable works fine as in local.

Is it possible that the staging env is configured to not to initialize the `app` variable? Where can I take a look?

Plus, a strange thing. The same behavior happens also if I make a custom, loading session data from the controller and passing them to the view.

**Controller**

```
$session = $this->get('session');

$content = $this->render(
            'blocks/logged_user_menu.html.twig',
            [
                'access_token_sc' => $session->get('access_token')
            ]
        );
```

**View**

```
{{ access_token_sc }}
```

I've read that I could take a look at [Security config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: sounds like there is a difference in the session-storage/handler. whats the session properties in app/config/config.yml ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I found `config.yml` with `session handler_id: session.handler.pdo` and a `config_test.yml` that includes the first and then has `session: storage_id: session.storage.mock_file`...I'll try something out in this direction

Comment: What have oyu tried to debug the problem? Why not set your local environment to `staging` and start up a debugger like XDebug?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @john Smith comment I found out that this kind of problem is related to `session.storage_id` in the `config.yml` file. In my case the test config file was using `mock_file` that inhibited the session behavior.

Leaving here the explanation for reference:
[MockFileSessionStorage class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockFileSessionStorage.php)

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage;

/**
 * MockFileSessionStorage is used to mock sessions for
 * functional testing when done in a single PHP process.
 *
 * No PHP session is actually started since a session can be initialized
 * and shutdown only once per PHP execution cycle and this class does
 * not pollute any session related globals, including session_*() functions
 * or session.* PHP ini directives.
 *
 * @author Drak <drak@zikula.org>
 */
class MockFileSessionStorage extends MockArraySessionStorage
{ ...
```